# Disable welcome messages for iPhoto 11 and iTunes 10 using MCX

Tags: osx-server, user-management

I would like to stop the initial startup screens appearing for iPhoto 11 and iTunes 10. There is Welcome screen for iPhoto and an Tutorials screen for iPhoto. Does anyone know what MCX keys I need to make them stop (if indeed it is possible)? Or any other method I can use to stop these screens?